# Who are the people walking with Hitler?

Tags: nazi-germany, hitler, identification

[image]I was going through my late Uncles WWII photo album from his time in the US Army. To my surprise I came across one page dedicated to the Nazi army. No idea how he came about these pictures. It looks like it was taken from his camera but do not see how that was possible. I am thinking it was maybe taken from a fallen Nazi soldier.

Who are the Nazi soldiers pictured with Hitler?

[image]

Comment: Is this the highest resolution scan you can get? All the faces are out of focus, making identification difficult unless the scene can be located somewhere else.

Comment: The only one I can even hazard a guess at is that perhaps it is [Albert Bormann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albert_Bormann) on Hitler's immediate left, in foreground

Comment: Even a higher resolution scan across the faces, with the current picture as context, would help tremendously. Likewise any additional details of the uniforms and rank insignia would help identify service and narrow down possibilities.

Comment: [Goebbels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Goebbels) might be a possibility for the face right above Hitler's right shoulder.

Comment: Where did you get the photo from? Context is very helpful..

Comment: An aside - this is from your uncle's personal collection? Wow, that's amazing! Perhaps consider looking in to a high quality "digitizer" so you can put these online for others, especially historians. (assuming you're comfortable sharing his personal photos/memories).

Comment: Semaphore, unfortunately I cannot add more than I already stated. My uncle fought in WWII with the army. During his time in the war he took many pictures. He had some of downed planes, damaged tanks, the Rome colluseum, of himself loading artellary and etc... in the middle of ne of his books he had a page with about 5 pictures of Nazi’s. The one I posted stood out because it was of Hiler. My uncle died in the 1980’s and anyone that would know about his photo album has also passed on. So I have no one to contact in regards to how he obtained the picture.

Comment: BruceWayne, I currently do not own the photo album but it is promise to me sometime in the future. I have no problem digitizing and adding online once I own them.

Comment: Peter, unfortunately the photo album is back with my mom. That was the clearest my phone could take. I did zoom in and just posted that one too. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Since @tohuwawohu identified the place, I suppose next step is to identify the uniforms. From my limited knowledge, left to right, we have 1. a Luftwaffe uniform, 2. a weird beltless uniform that I can't relate to anything, 3. an SS uniform, 4. possibly an SA uniform (the man partially covered by Hitler), 5. another SS, 6. and 7. two army officers (one in the forefront, the other partially behind him), 8. another uniform similar to 2. above, and 9. and 10. two further SS officers. Can someone correct me or add some more information?

Comment: Here ( http://www.ansichtskarten-center.de/webshop/shop/ProdukteBilder/59038/AK_55177409_gr_1.jpg ) is a better version of this photograph. It is for sale at http://www.ansichtskarten-center.de/hitler/7902-blaubeuren-foto-ak-hitler-wk-ii , for 26 euros (or was; it says that it is *bereits verkauft*). So the location is confirmed, but it looks like the photograph is already in public domain. And it seems to be a postal card; the other side is http://www.ansichtskarten-center.de/webshop/shop/ProdukteBilder/59038/AK_55177409_gr_2.jpg .

Comment: @Luis Henrique - The photo we have is not a postal card. It is identical to the original photo going for 150 Euro like here https://www.todocoleccion.net/militaria-fotografia/foto-original-adolf-hitler-marcaje-alfa-lupex~x29224082. It has the same perforated edges. The one my family has is actually in better condition except it is glued to a page in the photo album. I wonder what this picture was originally for and how people obtained it.

Comment: That's strange... perhaps your uncle photographed a post card?

Comment: As for the strange uniforms, might they be Baden-Württenberg state police?

Comment: I guess it is possible he photographed it but it does not look like it to me.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Regarding place and date: The picture was taken in [Blaubeuren, Germany](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blaubeuren). In the background, a part of the [Blaubeuren Abbey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blaubeuren_Abbey) is visible (its western portal):

[image: von Schilling Thomas (Eigenes Werk) [CC BY-SA 4.0 (https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0)], via Wikimedia Commons]

<sup>Source: Wikipedia Commons, Schilling Thomas (Own Work) [CC BY-SA 4.0] (https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0)</sup>

The place is about 100 meters south of the „[Blautopf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blautopf)“, a famous little pond in Blaubeuren; today, the street is named „[Blautopfstraße](https://goo.gl/maps/oD5BQHFV7q22)“. Guessing by the shadows cast, the photo was taken around noon.

Maybe, the photo depicts Hitler's visit in Blaubeuren where he had lunch on September 5th 1933 (according to [Sandner's „Itinerar“](https://books.google.de/books?id=_A9DDwAAQBAJ&lpg=PT602&dq=hitler%20ulm%20blaubeuren&hl=de&pg=PT602#v=onepage&q=hitler%20ulm%20blaubeuren&f=false)), on occasion of his stay in [Ulm where he attended a maneuver of the 5. Reichswehrregiment on September 5th and 6th, 1933](https://books.google.de/books?id=U8lsAwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA361&dq=ulm%20september%201933&hl=de&pg=PA361#v=onepage&q=ulm%20september%201933&f=false) (this may explain the presence of high-ranking military people at that place and time). There are [archival sources](http://www.landesarchiv-bw.de/plink/?f=1-1504479) about a meeting between Hitler and some high-ranking Reichswehr officers at Ulm: Werner von Blomberg, General Kurt von Hammerstein, Generalleutnant Curt Liebmann and General Hans Freiherr Seutter von Lötzen. Guessing by a [slightly better (but cropped) version of that photo](https://cloud10.todocoleccion.online/militaria-fotografia/tc/2011/11/09/29224082.jpg) (that was also available as picture postcard: see [here](http://www.ansichtskarten-center.de/hitler/7902-blaubeuren-foto-ak-hitler-wk-ii) and [here](https://www.todocoleccion.net/militaria-fotografia/foto-original-adolf-hitler-marcaje-alfa-lupex~x29224082)), the person at Hitler's left may be [Werner von Blomberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Werner_von_Blomberg) (wearing his "[Pour le Mérite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pour_le_M%C3%A9rite)"?), at that time Minister of Defense. The person at the very right of the photo may be [Heinrich Himmler](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heinrich_Himmler) (???). Regarding Goebbels: It [seems that he didn't accompany Hitler to Ulm but returned to Berlin](https://books.google.de/books?id=Nr2dCgAAQBAJ&lpg=PA263&dq=man%C3%B6ver%20september%201933%20ulm&hl=de&pg=PA263#v=onepage&q=man%C3%B6ver%20september%201933%20ulm&f=false) after attending the [Nuremberg Rally](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuremberg_Rally) from August 30 to September 3, 1933.

Comment: Good work. I agree that Blomberg is a more likely candidate than Borman for the figure at Hitler's immediate left. The entire uniform and medals seems nearly identical to that in his Wikipedia picture, as well as his facial features.

Comment: Tell me you did know the building beforehand. Otherwise: tell me how you did that. Amazing. – As a side note: I guess the guy on the right is too well built and plump to be [HH](https://cdn.images.dailystar.co.uk/dynamic/1/photos/77000/himmler-germany-464077.jpg). And can you identify or make sense of the one to the left of AH in what looks like undecorated imperial dress? (Or is this just some ticket inspector?)

Comment: Wow! Great detective work! All I can say is the picture I have is not postcard. But the pictures are identical for sure. So this would also confirm my uncle did not take the picture because he enlisted in the army in 1942.

Comment: The pics are not quite identical: One strange thing: on the linked pic is a ghost in front of the presumed "Himmler"; although the cropped one is sharper than the above. –  The person looking over AH's shoulder: could that be Rommel?

Comment: @LangLangC: (1) Doesn't look particularly like Rommel to me. (2) Rommel was merely an OberstLieutnant stationed a couple hundred KM away when the picture was taken, and wouldn't meet Hitler until a Sep. 30, 1934, inspection of his battalion.

Comment: LangLang, not sure what you are referring to as a ghost. Since the picture is glued on the page of his photo album, I am assuming what you are seeing is the glue seeping through the photo.

Comment: @LangLangC: to be honest: identifying the place was pure luck. Somehow, i found [this photo](https://www.todocoleccion.net/militaria-fotografia/foto-original-adolf-hitler-marcaje-alfa-lupex~x29224082) using Google. On its back, there's a stamp "Photo-Wörz Blaubeuren". Now, searching for churches in Blaubeuren, identification was easy. Then, i tried to find information about any visits of Hitler in Blaubeuren, and so on...

Comment: @LangLangC: regarding the person at his right - again just guessing - maybe it's Hitler's chauffeur? At least, they went to Blaubeuren by car.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Whether he was stationed at Goslar or Dresden, it was a 'Manöver', soldiers met there. If it is certain that Rommel met AH first in 34, then it's off. Visually, it's a match in my eyes.

Comment: @Mark Something is fishy about those pictures. The [slighty better but cropped](https://cloud10.todocoleccion.online/militaria-fotografia/tc/2011/11/09/29224082.jpg) has a ghost to the right in the front. At least one of the pics was touched.

Comment: @tohuwawohu: He's definitely lower ranking (or at least less prestigious) than the others - simpler uniform, no medals - but the cap is an officer's not an enlisted man's or NCO's I believe.

Comment: @tohuwawohu: I don't think it can be Julius Schreck, but Erich Kempka is possible. Both were officers, but in the SS not the Wehrmacht.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens I also had Kempka in mind, the face seems to match, but I never saw a pic of him from that time not in SS uniform. Then the drivers numbered into the sixty range? But if all FBK members were SS, then it is still an odd sight with this uniform. (Today was washing day)

Comment: @LangLang... the one you are referring to that has a ghost is not the one we have in our possession.